# Searching through JSON records with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 7
MySQL 8
```

I have an Author Model, and one of the fields is personal_info, the migration for it was:

```
class CreateAuthors < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :authors do |t|
      t.json :personal_info
      ....
```

The format of the JSON that gets stored in the personal_info field is:

```
{
  'email':'someemail',
  'address':{
    'street':'Elm Street',
    'city':'some city',
    'state':'CA'
    'zip':'94001'
  }
}
```

What I would like to do, is query for all authors who live in California. I have not seen any examples where a record with nested JSON structures are used.

I tried the following:

```
authors = Author.where("personal_info->'$.address'->'$.state' = :state", state: 'CA')
authors = Author.where("personal_info->'$.address->$.state' = :state", state: 'CA')
authors = Author.where("personal_info->'address'->>'state' = ?", "CA")
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's been a while but I thought you just use a `.` to chain the child keys like: `personal_info->>'$.address.state'`

Comment: @Beartech it's not giving me an error, but it's returning an empty array [] when I know there are records that match the critieria.

Comment: This is very symptomatic of *the unnessicary JSON anti-pattern* - if you are going to use this data when querying the records you should just use a table so that you can have a normalized structure and write sane SQL such as a simple join.  You are after all using a relational database and a ORM based around it. It makes a lot more sense to be able to do `Author.joins(:addesses).where(addesses: { state: 'CA'})`

Comment: @max Nevertheless, both MySQL 8 and Rails 7 support JSON fields, for a reason, primarily so I don't have to modify my DB schema every time a change is needed. Instead, adding a version to the JSON, will suffice.

Comment: Yeah but just because a tool exists doesn't mean its right for the job. I would argue you should put everything into your schema that you can know you'll need and then if you actually need dynamic fields then JSON can be a useful tool. But if you're using it out of laziness instead of tables and relations you're really just shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @EastsideDev I would confirm the query you are looking for in the database console to confirm your syntax. Something like `personal_info->"$.address.state" AS state FROM authors HAVING "state" = "CA"`

Comment: @Beartech I am using the console.

Comment: @max The point of doing JSON, is not to have extra time to watch FIFA matches. It's to minimize bugs, and be able to cleanly respond to requirements changes, using versioning, and last but not least, reduce table sprawl..

Comment: @EastsideDev, I meant the Mysql console, not the Rails console. So a pure SQL query in the database. The command line is `mysql db_name` Can you try that to see if your query works in the MySQL client?